# Print out each array value in the iteration, value is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to print out the content of the composed array. As you can see I call `console.log` at the end of the code and every value in the composed array is undefined. But if I call `console.log` at somewhere else such as `if` statement, the values are right. Please tell me why, thanks!

```js
$(function() {
  var text = $('p').text().split('');
  var letter = 0;
  var composed = [];
  $.each(text, function(index, value) {
    if (/\w/.test(value)) { // if the character is alphanumeric
      var prev = index - 1;
      var next = index + 1;
      if (/\w/.test(text[prev])) {
        composed[letter] = composed[letter] + value;

        if (!/\w/.test(text[next])) {
          console.log('composed[' + letter + '] = ' + composed[letter]);
          letter++;
        }
      } else {
        composed[letter] = value;

        if (!/\w/.test(text[next])) {
          console.log('composed[' + letter + '] = ' + composed[letter]);
          letter++;
        }
      }
    } else {
      composed[letter] = value;
      console.log('composed[' + letter + '] = ' + composed[letter]);
      letter++;
    }
    console.log('composed[' + letter + '] = ' + composed[letter]); // undefined
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Test both Chinese中文 ,alphbets and numbers.</p>
```

---

Comment: Just one thing that falls into sight: You are not closing the curly brackets after the follwing statement (twice!): `if (!/\w/.test(text[next])) {`

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Just added the missing pieces, thank you!

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you. Just fixed the missing brackets,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your composed[letter] is "undefined" because previous state is letter++;

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log('composed[' + letter + '] = ' + composed[letter - 1]);
```

this gives correct value

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
var letter = 0;
var composed = [];

function addLetter(letter, value) {
  // your could ignore white-space and punctuation there
  if (composed[letter]) composed[letter] += value
  else composed[letter] = value;

}
$(function() {
  var text = $('p').text().split('');
  $.each(text, function(index, value) {
    if (/\w/.test(value)) { // if the character is alphanumeric
      var prev = index - 1;
      var next = index + 1;
      if (/\w/.test(text[prev])) {
        addLetter(letter, value)
        if (!/\w/.test(text[next])) {
          letter++;
        }
      } else {
        addLetter(letter,value);
        if (!/\w/.test(text[next])) {
          letter++;
        }
      }
    } else {
      addLetter(letter, value)
      letter++;
    }
  });
  console.log(composed)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Test both Chinese中文 ,alphabets and numbers 1234.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check for spaces. to ensure the we are not manipulating spaces.

```
**if (/\w/.test(text[prev] && composed[letter]!=" "))**
```

--

```
$(function() {
  var text = $('p').text().split('');
  var letter = 0;
  var composed = [];
  $.each(text, function(index, value) {
    if (/\w/.test(value)) { // if the character is alphanumeric
      var prev = index - 1;
      var next = index + 1;
      if (/\w/.test(text[prev] && composed[letter]!=" ")) {
        composed[letter] = composed[letter] + value;

        if (!/\w/.test(text[next])) {
          console.log('composed[' + letter + '] = ' + composed[letter]);
          letter++;
        }
      } else {
        composed[letter] = value;

        if (!/\w/.test(text[next]) && composed[letter]!=" ") {
          console.log('composed[' + letter + '] = ' + composed[letter]);
          letter++;
        }
      }
    } else {
      composed[letter] = value;
      console.log('composed[' + letter + '] = ' + composed[letter]);
      letter++;
    }
    console.log('composed[' + letter + '] = ' + composed[letter]); // undefined
  });
});
```